# Can I "unwrap" this promise given by Axios without having to use async/await?

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I call this function:

```
let bing_web_search = function(search) {
    let searchEncoded = encodeURIComponent(search);
    return axios.get(
        'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search?q=' + searchEncoded + '+site:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/&mkt=en-us', {
            headers: { 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : process.env.BING_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY }
        })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.data.webPages;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

...inside this function in my controller:

```
router.get('/search/results', async function(req, res) {
    let searchResults = bing.bing_web_search(req.query.search_query);
    let test = await searchResults.then(function(results) {
        return results
    });

    res.render('../views/results', {
        test : test
    });
})
```

I didn't see having to use async/await in the Axios docs and I couldn't get this to work without them. I kept getting `Promise { pending}`, hence why I use `then()` twice thinking that the second `then()` would unwrap the promise. Is this possible without the async/await?

Comment: Async and await are only syntax sugar over promises. You can rewrite the code using `.then` only if you really want to, but it wouldn't actually achieve anything you couldn't do otherwise.

Comment: Be careful because your `.catch()` handler is "eating" errors and changing a rejected promise into a resolved promise with an `undefined` resolved value.  If you want to log an error, then rethrow afterwards such as `.catch(err => { console.log(err); throw err;});` to keep the promise rejected.

Comment: Looking at your calling code, I can't figure out how `test` would end up being anything but `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use async/await. You can do what you want like this:

```
router.get('/search/results', function(req, res) {
    const searchResults = bing.bing_web_search(req.query.search_query);

    searchResults.then(function(results) {
        res.render('../views/results', {
            test : results
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: So my concern with this is that I will eventually be passing in about 4 or 5 different API search results. Will this be scalable once I start connecting to them and needing to pass in more than one result? Or should I then try to consolidate all of my results into one variable to pass in?

Comment: @A.Cam - If you have multiple promises, you use `Promise.all()` with them to be notified when all the promises are done. It is scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of queries then you can use `Promise.all` as jfriend stated:

```
router.get('/search/results', function(req, res) {
  Promise.all(
    req.query.search_queries.map(//assuming you have an array of queries
      query=>bing.bing_web_search(query)
    )
  ).then(
    results=>
      res.render('../views/results', {
        test : results
      })
  );
});
```

Async await syntax will look like this:

```
router.get('/search/results', async function(req, res) {
  const results = await Promise.all(
    req.query.search_queries.map(//assuming you have an array of queries
      query=>bing.bing_web_search(query)
    )
  );
  res.render('../views/results', {
    test : results
  })
});
```

Note that both don't catch any errors (your `bing_web_search` catches errors and resolves to undefined).